# Python Pandas Dataframe: Value of second recent day for each person

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to group one dataframe conditional on another dataframe using Pythons pandas dataframes:

The first dataframe gives the holidays of each person:

```
import pandas as pd
df_holiday = pd.DataFrame({'Person': ['Alfred', 'Bob', 'Charles'], 'Last Holiday': ['2018-02-01', '2018-06-01', '2018-05-01']})
df_holiday.head()
```

```
    Last Holiday    Person
0   2018-02-01  Alfred
1   2018-06-01  Bob
2   2018-05-01  Charles
```

The second dataframe gives the sales value for each person and month:

```
df_sales = pd.DataFrame({'Person': ['Alfred', 'Alfred', 'Alfred','Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Bob','Charles','Charles','Charles','Charles','Charles','Charles'],'Date': ['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01','2018-04-01', '2018-05-01', '2018-06-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01','2018-04-01', '2018-05-01', '2018-06-01'], 'Sales': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]})
df_sales.head(15)
```

```
    Date    Person  Sales
0   2018-01-01  Alfred  1
1   2018-02-01  Alfred  2
2   2018-03-01  Alfred  3
3   2018-01-01  Bob 4
4   2018-02-01  Bob 5
5   2018-03-01  Bob 6
6   2018-04-01  Bob 7
7   2018-05-01  Bob 8
8   2018-06-01  Bob 9
9   2018-01-01  Charles 10
10  2018-02-01  Charles 11
11  2018-03-01  Charles 12
12  2018-04-01  Charles 13
13  2018-05-01  Charles 14
14  2018-06-01  Charles 15
```

Now, i want the sales number for each person before his last holiday, i.e. the outcome should be:

```
    Date    Person  Sales
0   2018-01-01  Alfred  1
7   2018-05-01  Bob 8
12  2018-04-01  Charles 13
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do `merge` then `filter` and `drop_duplicates`

```
df=df_holiday.merge(df_sales).loc[lambda x : x['Last Holiday']>x['Date']].drop_duplicates('Person',keep='last')
Out[163]: 
     Person Last Holiday        Date  Sales
0    Alfred   2018-02-01  2018-01-01      1
7       Bob   2018-06-01  2018-05-01      8
12  Charles   2018-05-01  2018-04-01     13
```